# How do I center text on a web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

This is what I have and it is not being centered. It's all the way to the left for some reason.

```
<div>
        <asp:Label ID="eagleReplicationManagerLabel" runat="server" CssClass="eagleReplicationManagerLabel">
                Eagle Replication Manager
        </asp:Label>
    </div>
```

css for it:

```
.eagleReplicationManagerLabel
{
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #0000FF;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Try the css suggested in this post http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually working but you couldn't see the result because it is rendered as a span which takes the exact width of its content. So the text didn't have enough space to adjust.

Increasing the width in your css style will show you why

```
.eagleReplicationManagerLabel
{
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #0000FF;
    text-align: center;
    width:500px;
}
```

Comment: this worked. but i had to adjust the width to 100% (so it centers on the screen). thx :)

Comment: my solution was based on this too, but changed `position: fixed` for `display: block` so the label doesn't get stuck when the page scrolls down

Answer (score 2):

The `text-align: center;` needs to be on the `<div>` that contains the label.

Answer (score 0):

the text is centered but is is an inline element so it is only as wide as the text inside.

That is why you can't tell that it is centered.

Give it some width or make it block and you will see the centering.

```
.eagleReplicationManagerLabel
{
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #0000FF;
    text-align: center;
    display:block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `asp:Label` is rendered as a `span` on html and `span` elements are, by default, styled with `display:inline`; as a result, your CSS class does nothing.

If you want to center the text in the DIV, set the `text-align:center` on the DIV or set `display:block` on `.eagleReplicationManagerLabel`

```
.eagleReplicationManagerLabel
{
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #0000FF;
    text-align: center;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.center{
width:200px;
margin:auto;
}

.eagleReplicationManagerLabel
{
 position: fixed;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #0000FF;
 text-align: center;
}
<div>
<div class="center">
    <asp:Label  Text="Eagle Replication Manager" ID="eagleReplicationManagerLabel1" runat="server" CssClass="eagleReplicationManagerLabel"></asp:Label>
</div>

</div>
```